# Mule Quartz Job Issues

Tags: mule, quartz-scheduler

I have 2 separate Quartz jobs in a Mule application which have different instance names as well. However, they both have the same cronExpression of 2 hours. I have given a start delay that's different for both. However, when the application starts only 1 of the flows ever runs. The other flow never runs. Can one not have the same cronExpressions for 2 separate quartz flows?
Quartz Configuration 1

```
<quartz:connector name="orderServiceQuartzConnector" 
    validateConnections="true" doc:name="Order Quartz">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName" 
                                           value="orderQuartzScheduler"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.threadPool.class" 
                        value="org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount" 
             value="1"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy" 
                                                value="false"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export" 
                                                         value="false"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.jobStore.class" 
                                  value="org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore"/>
</quartz:connector>

 Quartz Configuration 2

<quartz:connector name="fileServiceQuartzConnector" 
  validateConnections="true" 
                                       doc:name="Order Quartz">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName" 
                                            value="fileQuartzScheduler"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.threadPool.class" 
                              value="org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount" 
             value="1"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy" 
                                                        value="false"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export" 
                                                      value="false"/>
    <quartz:factory-property key="org.quartz.jobStore.class" 
                                    value="org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore"/>
     </quartz:connector>

   //orderServiceQuartzConnector is used in this flow every 2 hours

   <flow name="OrderProcess" tracking:enable-default-events="true" 
            processingStrategy="synchronous">
      <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Order 
      Updates" cronExpression="0 0 0/2* * ?" startDelay="50000"
                     jobName="EventUpdates" repeatInterval="0"    connector-
    ref="orderServiceQuartzConnector">
       <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
         <flow-ref name="process.orders" />
   </flow>
```

//Using other Quartz Connector fileServiceQuartzConnector also 2 hours

```
      <flow name="CsvFileProcess" tracking:enable-default-events="true" 
          processingStrategy="synchronous">
      <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File 
         Receipt" cronExpression="0 0 0/2* * ?" startDelay="80000"
                     jobName="FileProcess" repeatInterval="0"    connector-
                              ref="fileServiceQuartzConnector">
       <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
         <flow-ref name="process.csv.file" />
   </flow>
```

Why is only 1 flow running i.e. the Order Service flow?

Comment: what version of mule are you using?. You have `maxThreadsActive="1"` in the configuration and along with flow processing as synchronous. Try increasing the thread and see the behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only want one thread to run the synchronous process since both flows are long running, they could run for several hours. I don't want another flow to be tirggered until the current ones are complete.  I am using version 3.7